# matplotlib: log transform counts in hist2d

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a simple way to get log transformed counts when plotting a two dimensional histogram in matplotlib? Unlike the [`pyplot.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) method, the [`pyplot.hist2d`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d) method does not seem to have a log parameter.

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

matrix, *opt = np.histogram2d(x, y)
img = plt.imshow(matrix, norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap = mpl.cm.gray, 
                 interpolation="None")
```

Which plots the expected histogram, but the axis labels show the indices of the bins and thus not the expected value.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's kind of embarrassing, but the answer to my question is actually in the [`docstring`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py) of the corresponding code:

```
Notes
-----
    Rendering the histogram with a logarithmic color scale is
    accomplished by passing a :class:`colors.LogNorm` instance to
    the *norm* keyword argument. Likewise, power-law normalization
    (similar in effect to gamma correction) can be accomplished with
    :class:`colors.PowerNorm`.
```

So this works:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
par = plt.hist2d(x, y, norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap=mpl.cm.gray)
```