# How to cluster data according to density?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to cluster data according to the density of the data points.

[image: 1]

I want to draw contours around these regions according to the density.Like so:

[image: 2]

I am trying to adapt the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105364/how-can-i-make-a-scatter-plot-colored-by-density-in-matplotlib) to get to this point:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# Generate fake data
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=1000)

# Calculate the point density
xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

# Sort the points by density, so that the densest points are plotted last
idx = z.argsort()
x, y, z = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img=ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, edgecolor='')

plt.show()
```

Comment: [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)

maybe the code here helps you

Comment: So what went wrong with what you have tried? Also, include the data and code used to plot the above so people can help (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EdSmith : I copy/pasted those pictures from a scientific paper,

Comment: Try somethink like http://digitizer.sourceforge.net/ or equivalent

Answer (score 0):

To cluster by density, try an algorithm like [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). However, it looks like you rather want to estimate the density itself and not cluster points together because you want to color your output by density. In that case, use a simple Kernel density estimate (`density` function in R) or an adaptive kernel density estimate if you have broad and very sharp peaks at the same time. Example for Matlab: [Adaptive Kernel density estimate on Matlab File Exchange](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/58312-kernel-density-estimator-for-high-dimensions)