# Change the color of the plot depending on the density (stored in an array) in line plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, line-plot

I have a file with three columns, lets say, x y z. I need to plot x Vs y but I need to change the color of that (x,y) value depending on its density (stored in z column). I understand that I need to use color map and have to map the values of the color with the z array. I can do that via scatter plot as also shown in this post: [How can I make a scatter plot colored by density in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105364/how-can-i-make-a-scatter-plot-colored-by-density-in-matplotlib)

But I do not need the scatter plot, I need the points to be connected, ie I need a line plot. Can it be done in line plot?

Comment: [This example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) may help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to connect points from a scatter plot directly. But the same effect can be achieved by plotting a line behind the scatter points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-3,6)
y = np.sin(x)
z = 0.5+np.random.rand(len(x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, color="k", marker=None, zorder=0)
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100, edgecolor='',zorder=3)
plt.colorbar(sc, label="Density")

plt.show()
```

[image]