# How to show full results in plt.show matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following the exact instructions in top answer here:

[How can I make a scatter plot colored by density in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105364/how-can-i-make-a-scatter-plot-colored-by-density-in-matplotlib)

my plot displays only 10,000 results when I actually have 133,607 results. How do I expand the graph to show all results? Any ideas? Couldn't find anything online. Thanks!

Comment: You can be assured that if a you plot a scatter plot with N values, it will plot all N values. That being said, there is no way we can solve your problem.

Comment: hmmm alright, thanks!