# Multi Dimensional approximation in Python

Tags: python, scipy, approximation

I need to approximate (by the gaussian function) 2 or 3 dimensional data sets using Python, but i found only interpolation methods. Anyone have heard about some library, that can do that ?

Comment: What's wrong with [`random.gauss`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.gauss) ?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you really want to do. But using a grid summation approach like mine could work for you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451834/gaussian-summation-for-2d-scatter-plots-using-python

Comment: @Sneftel Sorry, I didn't know the OP wants to _fit_ a data model. I thought they want to _generate_ data sets.