# Plot with density using Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset with two features, and I used `Seaborn.relplot` to draw them one according to the other, and I got this result:

[image: Simple scatterplot]

But I would like to add the points density using Seaborn as we can observe in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526344/points-with-density-gradient) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105364/how-can-i-make-a-scatter-plot-colored-by-density-in-matplotlib), see plots below.

[image: Simple density]
[image]

How can I do it using Seaborn?

Comment: You can use the method in your second link directly with `sns.scatterplot`. Another option would be to overlay a bivariate kde plot [as in this example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/layered_bivariate_plot.html).

Comment: Thanks, but they don't use seaborn, just matplotlib.

Comment: Seaborn is built on top of matplotlib so you can use matplotlib techniques with plots that seaborn generates.

Comment: Thanks. In fact. I wanted to know if there was a seaboard built in function to do it.

Comment: As far as I can tell you need to provide values to either the `hue` or `c` param as your colour values (from `gaussian_kde`) along with the colormap that you want to use. That _is_ the built-in way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As in your [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107592/3279716) but using `sns.scatterplot` instead:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

values = np.vstack([tips["total_bill"], tips["tip"]])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)(values)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
sns.scatterplot(
    data=tips,
    x="total_bill",
    y="tip",
    c=kernel,
    cmap="viridis",
    ax=ax,
)
```

[image: Scatterplot with density colour mapped on points]

Alternatively, overlaying a `sns.kdeplot`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
sns.scatterplot(
    data=tips,
    x="total_bill",
    y="tip",
    color="k",
    ax=ax,
)
sns.kdeplot(
    data=tips,
    x="total_bill",
    y="tip",
    levels=5,
    fill=True,
    alpha=0.6,
    cut=2,
    ax=ax,
)
```

[image: Scatterplot with overlaid kde plot]