# Attempting to create a color map for most overlapping points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

I'm running into an issue trying to create a color map within a scatterplot. Here's the portion of my code:

```
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

    f, ax = plt.subplots()

    xy = np.vstack([x, y])
    xy = xy[~np.isnan(xy)]
    z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

    idx = z.argsort()
    x, y, z = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx]

    plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='Reds', alpha=0.5)
```

`x` and `y` are both columns within my panda dataframe and they both do have `NaN` values. I tried taking out all the `NaN` values by doing `~np.isnan(xy)` to only get actual values since it wasn't allowing me to take infs or NaNs since I believe `gaussian_kde()` was throwing that error. Also, both columns don't align with each other in terms of where those `NaN` values are and one column has more `NaN` values than the other. Both also have the same amount of elements. When I run my code, it just keeps running and I have to stop it. Any ideas what's possibly wrong?

Comment: When posting your example please show the libs you are importing. We do not know where `gaussian_kde` comes from.

What are the typical size of the x and y vectors ?

Comment: @Liris I went ahead and updated to add the imported packages. x and y vectors are around 200k in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter the Nans using:

```
inds = ~np.logical_or(np.isnan(x), np.isnan(y))
x = x[inds]
y = y[inds]
```

From this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105364/how-can-i-make-a-scatter-plot-colored-by-density-in-matplotlib), I think your code should look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# Generate fake data
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=1000)

# removing nans in both vectors at the same place
inds = ~np.logical_or(np.isnan(x), np.isnan(y))
x = x[inds]
y = y[inds]

# Calculate the point density
xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100, edgecolor='')
plt.show()
```

Just keep in mind that if x and y are very large vectors, `gaussian_kde` can take a long time to run. For a vector length of 50000, it takes about  40.5 sec to run.

Comment: I went ahead and compiled, it worked! Interesting, it did take 300 seconds for it to compile due to the large vector sizes I have. Is there anyway to reduce this time without using gaussian_kde? I'm trying to create a colormap that would display the areas with the most overlapping points.

Comment: I don't think so. If you have a number of point large enough, you can pick some of them randomly to reduce the number of point you will feed to `gaussian_kde` !