# Colour points in scatter plot based on density

Tags: python, matplotlib, deprecated

I'm quite new to matplotlib, and I'm looking to make my scatterplots look a bit nicer. I have a lot of points to plot, so I'm looking into colouring them based on density for better readability.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105364) which solved the problem... in 2013. Now when I try to run it, I get the error message `ValueError: Using a string of single character colors as a color sequence is not supported. The colors can be passed as an explicit list instead.`

How can I update this code to the current matplotlib release? Or is there something else that I'm missing causing the error? I'm using it in a Jupyter notebook, if that matters at all.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
# Generate fake data
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=1000)

# Calculate the point density
xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

# Sort the points by density, so that the densest points are plotted last
idx = z.argsort()
x, y, z = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=50, edgecolor='')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just remove the `edgecolor=''` from `ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=50, edgecolor='')` and it will plot.

Comment: You can use `edgecolor='none'` for a fully transparent edge.  Or `linewidths=0`. Default the edgecolor is equal to the facecolor.  With very small dots it can help to remove the edge, but for `s=50` there doesn't seem to be a lot of benefits.

Comment: @JohanC if you type it into an answer, I'll accept it. I was too focused on the `c=z` part to even think of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API changes in new version of matplotlib, replace your code with:

```
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=50, edgecolor=['none'])
```