# 1D scatter plot colored by density

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, density-plot, datashader

I was wondering whether it was possible to use `mpl-scatter-density` or `datashader` to create  a 1D scatter plot colored by density as it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105364/how-can-i-make-a-scatter-plot-colored-by-density) for the 2D case.

It can be done with `gaussian_kde`, but it is quite slow when the number of points that I want to represent are above 10k.

Also, is it there a way to do the `mpl-scatter-density` approach without defining axis as `fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='scatter_density')` and by just creating them with `plt.subplots`?

I have tried to do so by using the `ScatterDensityArtist` from `mpl_scatter_density` without success.

Here is some sample code of the 1D scatter plot colored by density using `gaussian_kde`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# Generate fake data
data_x = np.broadcast_to(np.array([[1], [2], [3]]), (2, 3, 1000))
data_y = data_x*np.random.normal(size=(2,3,1000))

# Create subplots
nrows = 1
ncols = 2
size = 5
fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(
    nrows,
    ncols,
    figsize=(16/9*ncols*size,nrows*size),
    squeeze=False
)
for i,ax_row in enumerate(ax_array):
    for j,axes in enumerate(ax_row):
        
        index = nrows*i+j
        
        x = data_x[index,:,:]
        y = data_y[index,:,:]
        
        for x_values,y_values in zip(x,y):
            z_values = gaussian_kde(y_values)(y_values)
            idx = z_values.argsort()

            x_values, y_values, z_values = x_values[idx], y_values[idx], z_values[idx]

            axes.scatter(
                x_values,y_values,
                c=z_values, s=10,
                cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Reds')
            )
plt.show()
```

[image: the previous code produces this image.]

Answer (score 0):

Add subplot_kw to your plt.subplots arguments:

```
fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(
    nrows,
    ncols,
    figsize=(16/9*ncols*size,nrows*size),
    squeeze=False,
    subplot_kw={'projection': 'scatter_density'}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to evaluate the KDE at all the `y_values`, which is going to be slow when it consists of many points, you can evaluate it at fewer points (say 100) and then use those to interpolate to get the required `z_values`. I find this is of order 50 times quicker (when `y_values` has 10000 samples and the interpolator evaluates the KDE at 100 points). E.g.,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# get interp1d
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


# create interpolator
def interpolated(y_values, npoints=100):
    # set y values at which to interpolate
    yvals = np.linspace(y_values.min(), y_values.max(), npoints, endpoint=True)

    # generate the interpolation function
    ifunc = interp1d(yvals, gaussian_kde(y_values)(yvals))
    return ifunc(y_values)


# Generate fake data
data_x = np.broadcast_to(np.array([[1], [2], [3]]), (2, 3, 10000))
data_y = data_x*np.random.normal(size=(2,3,10000))

# Create subplots
nrows = 1
ncols = 2
size = 5
fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(
    nrows,
    ncols,
    figsize=(16/9*ncols*size,nrows*size),
    squeeze=False
)

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Reds')

for i,ax_row in enumerate(ax_array):
    for j,axes in enumerate(ax_row):
        
        index = nrows*i+j
        
        x = data_x[index,:,:]
        y = data_y[index,:,:]
        
        for x_values,y_values in zip(x,y):
            # use interpolator to get z_values
            z_values = interpolated(y_values)
            
            idx = z_values.argsort()

            x_values, y_values, z_values = x_values[idx], y_values[idx], z_values[idx]

            axes.scatter(
                x_values,y_values,
                c=z_values, s=10,
                cmap=cmap
            )
plt.show()
```