# Density scatter plot with legend

Tags: r, legend, scatter-plot, density-plot

Following-up on a question that has already been answered regarding the scatterplot density (see [R Scatter Plot: symbol color represents number of overlapping points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093935/r-scatter-plot-symbol-color-represents-number-of-overlapping-points)), I would like to know if there is a way to add the legend of the scatterplot, let's say for instance to the solution proposed by O'brien?

Comment: Read further, see the next answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17094758/2747709. Use hexbin or functions in ggplot to get legend