# Scatter plot colored by density in Scilab

Tags: plot, scatter-plot, scilab

I have a large data table of numbers in several columns (table.dat), which I import to Scilab 6.0 as a matrix by

```
A=fscanfMat('table.dat');
```

Then two columns of this matrix are taken as x- and y-coordinates of points in the plane. The command

```
scatter(A(:,1),A(:,2),0,".")
```

now generates a nice point cloud, but I want to color each point in this scatter plot according to the number density of data points in the plane, i.e. the spatial density of nearby points. For example, points should be colored dark blue in regions of high density and red in regions of lower density, with a smooth transition over all rainbow colors in between.

In this thread the question is answered for Python: 
[How can I make a scatter plot colored by density in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105364/how-can-i-make-a-scatter-plot-colored-by-density-in-matplotlib)

But how can this be achieved in Scilab?

Comment: I think you'd like to take a look at the ``stixbox`` toolbox for Scilab: https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/stixbox. The main function in that Python solution is the ``gaussian_kde`` from SciPy, and this toolbox provide a ``ksdensity`` for kernel smoothing density estimate. Unfortunately my Scilab crashes when I try to run it. Maybe you'll be luckier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to your problem is achieved by:

1. Calculating the [kernel density estimate (KDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) of your data, `d`;
2. Using `rainbowcolormap(n)` to create a color map `m` with `n` colors;
3. Ploting your data like this: `scatter(x,y,s,d,"fill"); set(gcf(),"color_map",m);`, where `s` is the size of the marker in the plot.

Since I could not use the [`stixbox` toolbox for Scilab](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/stixbox), I decided to come up with a workaround for this problem, so prepare yourself of a long answer.

### Pure Scilab solution

Firstly, I implemented `kernel_density()` on a Scilab macro. Its inputs are `x`, an n-by-p data matrix, and `h` the bandwidth. What it does is that it counts how many points lie within a circle/sphere/n-sphere of radius `h` centered in each data point.

I am not very experienced in this field of Statistics, so I had to read about KDE. It turned out that this solution of mine is actually one KDE method which uses a kernel with [constant and equal weight for the neighbors](https://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/621/F10/notes/10-28.pdf) (hence the reason I renamed `h` to "bandwidth" instead of just "radius", and why I added a `2*h*n` factor to the calculation).

Also, because of my lack of knowledge, I couldn't implement a way to choose an optimum `h` automatically for a given data set, so you'll have to choose it by trial and error. However, reading about the [Scipy implementation of `gaussian_kde()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#r583), which I saw in the example you provided in your question, and also using hints from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111011/covariance-vs-bandwidth-of-kernel-density-estimate), and [this reference](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=qPCmAOS-CoMC&pg=PA73), I came up with a method to reduce to 4 the number of possible `h` (if your data has 2 dimensions). Perhaps a real statistician could validate it in the comments, or provide a better way:

1. Calculate the covariance matrix of the data set;
2. Multiply its square root by Scott's factor: `n ^ (-1 / (p+4))`;
3. Plot for all `h` and choose the one that gives the best visualization.

The original `kernel_density` function can still be found [here](https://gist.github.com/luispauloml/948839447ba4c9d293d46cd3291ca4f6) and it works fine for around 10³ points. If you're dealing with more than that, keep reading.

### C implementation

As noted in the comments section, the Scilab implementation is rather slow. To get better results, I implemented `kdec()` in C and linked it to a Scilab macro using `ilib_for_link()`. However, this method still have its problems (see warning note at the bottom).

To use this function on Scilab, you should have a compatible C compiler:

- If you use UNIX or UNIX-like system, you don't need to worry.
- If you use Windows, you should follow the instructions of [`mingw` toolbox](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw) and have it loaded into Scilab environment when you execute `kde()`.

First, you have to put `kdec.c` in the current Scilab directory.

```
//kdec.c
#include <math.h>

void kdec(double f[], double x[], double *h, int *n, int *p){
    /* x[]: (n*p)-by-1 array of data
     *  *h: bandwitdh
     *  *n: the number of points
     *  *p: the number of dimensions
     * f[]: the output
     *
     *  the local neighborhood density can be defined as (for constant weight):
     *   f(x0) = sum_from i_to n of K(||x_i - x_0|| <= h) / 2hn
     *   where: x0 is the observed point, which can have p-dimensions;
     *          K(a) = {1 if a == True
     *                 {0 if a == False
     */

    int n_ = *n; int p_ = *p; double h_ = *h;

    int d, j, k;
    double dif, norm;

    for(j = 0; j < n_; j++){
        f[j] = 0;

        for(k = 0; k < n_; k++){
            norm = 0;

            for(d = 0; d < p_; d++){
                dif = x[k + d*n_] - x[j + d*n_];
                norm = norm + dif * dif;
            }
            norm = sqrt(norm);

            if (norm <= h_){
                f[j] = f[j] + 1;
            }
        }


        f[j] = f[j]  / (2 * (h_) * (n_));
    }
}
```

Then, set `kde.sci` to call the `kdec` C function and wrap in the new Scilab `kde` function.

```
//kde.sci
if ~isdef('kde') then
    ilib_for_link('kdec','kdec.c',[],"c") //compile and create the new shared library
    exec('loader.sce',-1);                //load library
end

//create a wrapper function to improve interface with interface 'kdec'
function varargout = kde(x,h)
    //x: n-by-p matrix of data, each column is a dimension
    //h: bandwitdh

    [n, p] = size(x); //n: number of points
                      //p: number of dimensions
    x = x(1:$);
    if length(h) ~= 1 then
        error("kde(x,h): x should be n-by-p matrx; " +...
              "h shoud be scalar, positive, and real");
    end
    f = call('kdec'...
            , x     , 2, 'd'...
            , abs(h), 3, 'd'...
            , n     , 4, 'i'...
            , p     , 5, 'i'...
            ,'out'...
            ,[n,1]  , 1, 'd' );

    varargout = list(f)
endfunction
```

Since I did not get any better in Statistics, you still need to set `h` manually. However, after testing it some many times, it seems like the best result for 2D data is given by:

```
scotts_factor = n ^ (-1 / (p+4))
h = sqrt(abs(cov(A))) .* scotts_factor;
h = h(2);
```

Here is some test:

```
exec('kde.sci',-1);

//create data set
n = 1d4;
p = 2;
A = grand((n/2), 1, "nor", 0, 1);
A = [A, A * 3 + grand((n/2), 1, "nor", 0, 1)];
A = [ A ; [ A(:,1) * 0.8 , A(:,2) * 1.3 + 10 ] ];

//calculating bandwidth
scotts_factor = n ^ (-1 / (p+4))
h = sqrt(abs(cov(A))) .* scotts_factor;
h = h(2);

//calculate density
d = kde(A, h);

[d, idx] = gsort(d); //sorting data to plot higher-density points
idx = idx($:-1:1);   //over lower-density ones
d = d($:-1:1);       //(reversing densities matrix)
A = A(idx,:);        //(reordering data matrix)

//plotting
scf(); clf();
scatter(A(:,1), A(:,2), 10, d, "fill");

m = rainbowcolormap(32);  //create the rainbow color map
m = m($:-1:1,:);          //reverse it to get hotter colors on higher densities
set(gcf(),'color_map',m); //set the desired color map
```

The output is:

[image: Local neighborhood density plot for 10^4 random points]

### A warning note

Even after implementing it in C, it is still a high-cost function. Because of the two nested for-loops, it is O(n²).
I did a few measurements and these were the results:

```
 n (points)  |   10^3  | 5*10^3 |  10^4  |  10^5
-------------+---------+--------+--------+---------
 t (seconds) | 0.13751 | 1.2772 | 4.4545 | 323.34
```

It took more than 5min to run `kde()` for 100k points. Since you said you wanted to evaluate 1M points, I wouldn't recommend this solution either. Still, compare it to the pure Scilab solution: it takes around 5s for the latter to work on only 10³ points(!). This is already a huge improvement, but I'm afraid my solution won't get any better. Perhaps you should try reducing the number of samples, or look for other computing tools, such as [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093935/r-scatter-plot-symbol-color-represents-number-of-overlapping-points).

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! But unfortunately this loads forever when it's a really huge dataset (like 10^6 points). Any idea how to speed it up a bit?

Comment: @kolaka Actually, I also noticed that it's a really slow solution, but I forgot to make a note about that. Perhaps one solution would be to translate it to C or FORTRAN and use ``call`` to "import" i to the Scilab script, but I didn't investigate that.

Comment: @kolaka I updated this answer. Perhaps it is useful for you now.

Comment: Thanks @luispauloml , but for some reason I cannot get this working on my system (Windows 7). I obtain multiple errors from gcc, which I can't fix at the moment. Unfortunately, I also don't have any experience with using C compilers in Scilab.

Comment: @kolaka Dealing with these errors is a good opportunity to learn about this feature of calling C and FORTRAN functions. If you really want to stick with Scilab, perhaps you should ask someone about these errors, or even make another question on StackOverflow. Anyway, good luck with your task, whatever it may be.