# How to add an ellipse to a scatter plot colored by density in R?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, ellipse

I have a code that generates a scatter plot colored by density (inspired by this post [R Scatter Plot: symbol color represents number of overlapping points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093935/r-scatter-plot-symbol-color-represents-number-of-overlapping-points/17096661#17096661) ) :

```
## Data in a data.frame
x1 <- rnorm(n=1000, sd=2)
x2 <- x1*1.2 + rnorm(n=1000, sd=2)
df <- data.frame(x1,x2)

## Use densCols() output to get density at each point
x <- densCols(x1,x2, colramp=colorRampPalette(c("black", "white")))
df$dens <- col2rgb(x)[1,] + 1L

## Map densities to colors
cols <-  colorRampPalette(c("#FF3100", "#FF9400", "#FCFF00", 
                            "#45FE4F", "#00FEFF", "#000099"))(6)
df$col <- ifelse(df$dens >= 250, cols[1], ifelse(df$dens >= 200, cols[2], ifelse(df$dens >= 150, cols[3], ifelse(df$dens >= 100, cols[4], ifelse(df$dens >= 50, cols[5], cols[6])))))

## Plot it, reordering rows so that densest points are plotted on top
plot(x2~x1, data=df[order(df$dens),], pch=20, col=col, cex=2)
```

I'd like to add an ellipse where density values are equal to a fixed value, 200 for example. Exactly [like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adaaw.png), where an ellipse is drawn where density values are equal to 0.7. I don't have the code which generated the plot in this image so I really don't know how to get something like that

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

ggplot2 has a learning curve, but if you are willing to give it a go you can use geom_density_2d. I think it does what you want, at least for the most part.

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html

Comment: Yep indeed, I saw that it was possible with ggplot2, but I'd like to do this without it, just like in the picture I showed. I will try with this option if I don't find any other solution though, thank you !