# ggplot2 is taking too much time to render a plot

Tags: r, performance, ggplot2, benchmarking

I'm making a plot in R using ggplot2 library.
The thing is that a plot like the one produced by the code shown below is taking too much time to render, I'm using a PC with 16 GB RAM and an octacore i7 running windows 10 (R version = 3.6.2, 64 bit), as you can see in the benchmark shown below the process takes about 45 seconds to render, I ran the same code on rstudio.cloud (free version) and it took just 1 second, also I tried at another PC (8 GB RAM, i5, Windows 8.1, the graphics card is the same as mine) and it took 26 seconds.

The thing is the surprising slowness of the process on a reasonably high-end PC, in fact, it renders faster in a slower PC.

Is there a way to solve this issue, or at least, to know why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(30100, 6, 2), y=runif(30100, -3, 5))

df$color <- df$x*df$y

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color=color))+
  geom_point(shape=45, alpha=0.3)+
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "NA")+
  scale_colour_gradient2(mid="black",
                         low= "red", high  = "green")

benchplot(p1)
```

```
#>        step user.self sys.self elapsed
#> 1 construct      0.00     0.00    0.00
#> 2     build      0.28     0.02    0.29
#> 3    render      0.05     0.00    0.06
#> 4      draw      0.55    41.92   43.74
#> 5     TOTAL      0.88    41.94   44.09
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/46421908

Comment: I cannot reproduce these timings, my draw is in just below 2 secs. Have you tried exiting RStudio and restart?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted everything, that don't solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: What is your package version? Have you tried with another one?

Comment: My whole library is up to date, specifically ggplot is v. 3.2.1

Comment: Takes me 2 seconds on Ubuntu.  Does this happen outside RStudio?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, I have tried with the R console (outside RStudio), and it happens the same

Comment: Took 37s on my Windows 10 machine. This is probably a problem for Windows system. I had the same issue in the past in which some complicated plot took several minutes to render in Windows but only took tens of seconds on Linux Mint